# CSS - can't keep span 3 and span9 on same line when resizing window

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap in my RoR project. I have 2 columns, span3 and span9, which move while resizing the browser window: the span9 falls below and then returns to the side of the other span.

Here is the code, however the displayed result is different for some reason: http://jsfiddle.net/jUJn7/3/

HTML:

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span3 well" style="min-height:600px;">
        </div>
        <div class="span9 well" style="min-height:600px;">
        </div>
      </div>
```

I want the 2 spans to stay together in the same line. span3 must have a fixed width of 300px, span9 must adjust itself to the remaining space in the window.

I've tried the solutions in all other related questions with no success, and I've been trying to solve this problem for weeks, so I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: Why are you using span3 and span9 when you are overriding the width?

Comment: Because I'm new to CSS. And they appear to be already overriden by bootstrap, am I wrong?

Comment: span3 and span9 are css values set by bootstrap as part of the grid system. If you change the widths of the spans you will break the grid. You should create your own css class names rather than override the standard classes in bootstrap.

Comment: I moved my custom css file and the problem is exactly the same with the default css.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed span3 and flexible span9

html:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span3 well" style="min-height:600px;">
    </div>
    <div class="span9 well" style="min-height:600px;">
    </div>
  </div>
```

css:

```
.span3 {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}
.span9 {
  margin-left: 350px;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work at all in my original code, and works only partially in the example I linked to. Even if it worked, and if I understand correctly, isn't it a dirty solution to overlap them and use margin to fix it?